# Calculated fields (property) in crispy forms

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, calculated-field

It is possible to render calculated fields from model (@property) as readonly field or using HTML layout in crispy-forms?

Thanks in advance  for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your model instance to template using your views and get property value in template

**models.py**

```
from datetime import date
class DemoModel(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(mx_length=23)
     dob = models.DateTimeField()


    @property
    def age(self):
         return date.today().year - self.dob.year
```

**views.py**

```
def demoview(request):
   from .models import DemoModel
   instance = DemoModel.objects.first()
   return render(request, 'index.html' ,{'instance':instance})
```

**HTML**

```
 <p>DOB: {{ instance.dob }}</p>
 <p>AGE: {{ instance.age }}</p>
```

Comment: this is not crispy